# getHibernateTemplate().find(String query,Object values) equivalent in Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am working in Hibernate with Spring and used `Spring Hibernate template` (`getHibernateTemplate().find(String query,Object values)`) for replacing positioned parameter with values.
My query is:

```
from className classObject where classObject.variableOne = ? and classObject.variableTwo = ?
```

and my parameter is an `ArrayList<String>` with 2 values.

The `getHibernateTemplate().find(String query,Object values)` assigned the `ArrayList` values automatically in the where clause (As you can see, I didn't bind parameters manually) and returned me the result.
Now, I removed spring from my application and using only hibernate. So I would like to know,

- Is there any equivalent method available in hibernate (Session or
  Query) classes which gives same functionality as above where I will pass HQL and values?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use something like below

```
private void setParamValues(final String[] paramValues, SQLQuery query) {
        if (paramValues != null && paramValues.length > 0) {
            for (int liCnt = 0; liCnt < paramValues.length; liCnt++) {
                query.setString(liCnt, paramValues[liCnt]);
            }
        }
}
```

SQLQuery will replace the ? with passed parameter's value. Keep in mind sequence in the paramValues array should be the same as wrote in the query.

Above has been worked in my case, am sure this will work in your case as well.

This is not Hibernate method, your have to use this method before calling the database.

Comment: Hi Manoj, Thanks for the reply. I am aware of the solution above. We are iterating through parameter values(using for loop) and binding the parameter & input in the query. But I am looking for method which avoid setting the parameter binding (No for loop). Let me know if you find any. Thanks.